# Python Key Error when setting environment variable in supervisord

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I set an environment variable in supervisord:

```
[program:worker]
directory = /srv/app/
command=celery -A tasks worker -Q default -l info -n default_worker.%%h
environment=BROKER="amqp://admin:password@xxxxx:5672//"
```

Within my celeryconfig.py I then try to read that variable like this.

```
BROKER = os.environ['BROKER']
```

But I still get the key the error below, why?

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 106, in import_module
    return importlib.import_module(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/srv/app/celeryconfig.py", line 6, in <module>
    BROKER = os.environ['BROKER']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'BROKER
```

There is a file dump of the envs as suggested in the comments:

```
{
    'SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME': 'celery_default_worker',
    'TERM': 'linux',
    'SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL': 'unix: ///var/run/supervisor.sock',
    'UPSTART_INSTANCE': '',
    'RUNLEVEL': '2',
    'UPSTART_EVENTS': 'runlevel',
    'PREVLEVEL': 'N',
    'SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME': 'celery_default_worker',
    'UPSTART_JOB': 'rc',
    'PWD': '/',
    'SUPERVISOR_ENABLED': '1',
    'runlevel': '2',
    'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin: /usr/local/bin: /sbin: /bin: /usr/sbin: /usr/bin',
    'previous': 'N'
}
```

Comment: Strange - that does look correct at first pass. Possibly it will help your debugging to add `with open("/tmp/celery-environment.txt", "w") as f: f.write(repr(os.environ))` to your `celeryconfig.py`, then checking the `/tmp/celery-environment.txt` file to see what *is* in your environ?

Comment: Confirm the execution order. i.e. check if environment variable BROKER is set first in `supervisord:` or BROKER is read first in `CeleryConfig.py`. If `CeleryConfig.py` is read first, then there is no existence of BROKER as BROKER is set in `supervisord:`

Comment: Did you tell `supervisord` to pick up the changes, or otherwise restart `supervisord`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I reread and restarted with not joy.

Comment: I don't see why SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME and SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME are 'celery_default_worker' instead of just 'worker', is there a different program or group section that is relevant?

Comment: Accroding to supervisord docs, evironment value should be `KEY="val",KEY2="val2"`. Could it be that quotes are in fact significant?

Comment: Also, there's this bug: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/91 and https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/pull/550 please check your version of supervisord against when those patches were accepted.

Comment: @qarma: quoting is only needed when there are spaces or other meta values in the environment variable value portion.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a known bug in `supervisord`:

http://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/91 (kindof resolved)

http://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/pull/550 (pending)

In that case, moving your environment spec to global scope (for supervisord process itself) may be an acceptable workaround.

Finally, if all else fails, wrap `celery` in a shell script that accepts this specific environment variable as command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is most likely not the cause, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/28829162/1589147 for information on a related supervisord bug instead.**

I can reproduce your error partially. I do not see the error when celery runs within supervisor. I see the error when I try to run the task from an environment outside supervisor where I did not set the `BROKER` environment variable. `celeryconfig.py` is executed both by celery and by anything which tries to execute a task.

I am not certain if this issue is exactly what you have come across, if you could share how you are executing the tasks and when that exception is raised it may help.

For example, if I try to run the task from `ipython` an error is generated which matches your error.

```
In [1]: from tasks import add
In [2]: add.delay(2,3)
...
     21         if hasattr(self.__class__, "__missing__"):
     22             return self.__class__.__missing__(self, key)
---> 23         raise KeyError(key)
     24     def __setitem__(self, key, item): self.data[key] = item
     25     def __delitem__(self, key): del self.data[key]

KeyError: 'BROKER'
```

The `celeryconfig.py` is loaded locally in order to establish a connection to the celery broker and backend. I am unable to execute the task without setting the `BROKER` environment variable.

If I set the environment variable before executing my task the same code works for me.

```
In [3]: import os
In [4]: os.environ["BROKER"] = "broker is set"
In [5]: add.delay(2,3)
Out[5]: <AsyncResult: 0f3xxxx-87fa-48d7-9258-173bdd2052ca>
```

Here are the files I used in case it helps.

`supervisor.conf`: `supervisord -c supervisor.conf`

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
loglevel = info
nodaemon = true
identifier = supervisor

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:worker]
command=/app/srv/main-env/bin/celery -A tasks worker -Q default -l info -n default_worker.%%h
environment=BROKER="amqp://admin:password@xxxxx:5672//"
directory=/app/srv/
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/app/srv/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/app/srv/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

`celeryconfig.py`:

```
import os


BROKER = os.environ['BROKER']
```

`tasks.py`:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(
    'tasks',
    backend='amqp',
    broker='amqp://admin:password@xxxxx:5672//')
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
        return x + y
```

Comment: It does look like `supervisord` fails to apply subprocess environment variables.

Comment: I think the bugs you mentioned are a more likely cause of the error reported than my answer because the environment they display show numerous supervisor set environment variables. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer in order that I may upvote it?